# Google spreadsheet :Copying row from a range based on a cell value in that row

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to call a function which will copy all rows with quantity more than zero from the first tab (Ordering guide) and paste data in the second tab (Purchasing Order) in the same spreadsheet. See shared document.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ajccn3ZYtmd8WTFI3baDUd5eyRfCDXa1-cQJt7RGObE/edit?usp=sharing

Can someone please help me with this. I wrote the following code but itsn't working.

```
function AddLines(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Ordering guide" && r.getColumn() == 8 && r.getValue()>0) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Purchase Order");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a copy of your spreadsheet and tried to fix the script.
Here is the new copy of spreadsheet with fixed code and works well.

[Copy of PO Generation Spreasheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19xmi-ZKHefK1K7nQYjUtig_9JrgXIGHBcieOpS9ercg/edit#gid=0)

Here is the fixed code.

```
//Generate Purchase Order
function generatePO() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ogSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Ordering guide');
  var poSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Purchase Order');
  var lookupData = ogSheet.getRange(5, 1, ogSheet.getLastRow()-4, 9).getValues();
  var targetData = [];
  for(var i=0; i<lookupData.length; i++){
    if(lookupData[i][7] && lookupData[i][7] > 0){
      targetData.push(lookupData[i]);
    }
  }
  poSheet.getRange(5, 1, 50-4, 9).clearContent();
  poSheet.getRange(5, 1, targetData.length, 9).setValues(targetData);
  poSheet.activate();
}

//Reset Quantities
function resetQuantity(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ogSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Ordering guide');
  var qtyRange = ogSheet.getRange(5, 8, ogSheet.getLastRow()-4, 1).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Waqar. Thanks for the code above. It worked great. Now I am also trying to add an email button to this file which can email just the generated purchase order in a pdf format. I was able to run the script when logged in as an owner but not otherwise since there are few protected cells in the ordering guide tab. The message says: "You are trying to edit protected cells. Please contact the owner." Is there a way around this.

Comment: Here is the code I used for the email button: 
  var sheet_to_send = 'Purchase Order';
//-----------------------------
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = as.getSheets();
  for(var i in sheets){
    if (sheets[i].getName()!=sheet_to_send){
        sheets[i].hideSheet();
    }
}
MailApp.sendEmail('nitin.saini021@gmail.com', 'American Hotel Order', 'Attached is the order for processing. ', {attachments: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()});
  for(var i in sheets){
    if (sheets[i].getName()!=sheet_to_send){
        sheets[i].showSheet();
    }
}

Comment: In attachments, you need to export a PDF file and then attach PDF blob.

Comment: I couldn't make it to work. Can you check the code here please. Here is the link to the file that I am sharing with other users.       https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wiJJTiWWDg_9pNUYO5ferdKmKdwEb_5HLJI5T9uuUwo/edit?usp=sharing